# Silex 2/Symfony: Check CSRF token from security login form

Tags: symfony, silex

I do not use the "Form Service Provider" and manually output the CSRF token to my twig login form:

```
$csrf_token = $app['csrf.token_manager']->getToken('token_id'); //'TOKEN'
```

And in the login.html.twig:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
```

The manual (https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/providers/csrf.html) says, that it's possible to check the token like this:

```
$app['csrf.token_manager']->isTokenValid(new CsrfToken('token_id', 'TOKEN'));
```

But the whole login process is handled by the security component. How do I add the CSRF check to it?

This is my firewall setup:

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
'login' => array(
    'pattern' => '^/user/login$',
),
'secured_area' => array(
    'pattern' => '^.*$',
    'anonymous' => false,
    'remember_me' => array(),
    'form' => array(
        'login_path' => '/user/login',
        'check_path' => '/user/login_check',
    ),
    'logout' => array(
        'logout_path' => '/user/logout',
        'invalidate_session' => true
    ),
    'users' => function () use ($app) {
        return new UserProvider($app['db']);
    },
));
```

And the Login controller:

```
$app->get('/user/login', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
   $csrf_token = $app['csrf.token_manager']->getToken('token_id'); //'TOKEN'

    return $app['twig']->render('login.html.twig', array(
        'csrf_token' => $csrf_token,
    ));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `csrf` options to security config:

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
....
    'form' => array(
        'login_path' => '/user/login',
        'check_path' => '/user/login_check',
        'with_csrf' => true,
        'csrf_parameter' => '_csrf_token', // form field name
        'csrf_token_id' => 'token_id'
    ),
....
```

Comment: Doesn't work, nothing happens when I change the token to a wrong value. I would expect an exception then. Maybe these arguments are only for the "Form Service Provider".

Comment: The constructor of the SimpleFormAuthenticationListener has a 'CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager = null' argument and if this  $csrfTokenManager is still null, the csrf check is deactivated. So maybe I have to set the csrfTokenManager first, but where?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. Add parmeter `with_csrf`. I updated answer.